# Flask AppBuilder redirect_uri scheme control

Tags: python, flask, airflow, flask-appbuilder

I am working on deploying Apache Airflow with RBAC enabled, using AWS Cognito as an OAuth provider. I have all components set up, and have seen it work when running Airflow locally. However, I am seeing issues when I transition to deployments on AWS. Specifically, on the AWS side, the redirect_uri Flask AppBuilder is generating is using the HTTP scheme, while the redirects Cognito is expecting need to use HTTPS. This is causing login attempts to my app to fail due to a redirect mismatch, which I get via a 400 error in my browser client.

The closest thing I have been able to find via Google is the `enable_proxy_fix` variable, which I have tried setting equal to true in both `airflow.cfg` and in `webserver_config.py`, each to no avail. I have not been able to find anywhere the redirect scheme can be configured on the FAB side, and am looking for help.

Comment: Hey Kyle, did you manage to resolve this? I am hitting the same problem.

Comment: I managed to resolve all Cognito issues a while ago. I'm not sure what caused this anymore, but I extracted my Cognito url into an environment variable. In my case, it happens to be the same between local and AWS deployments, so it is always HTTPS. If you would like to see my source code for `webserver_config.py`, I can message you directly.